# Outdated, broken AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ajaxform

Recently migrated files over, and updated ca.py to run in Python3 instead of Python2. I have this AJAX request and JavaScript alerts work right before it, but not after. There are no console or other errors, so I'm not sure what exactly is wrong. Code below:

```
alert(input);
      var request = $.ajax({
      url: "ca.py",
      type: "GET",
      data: {rule: ruleNumber, numSteps: numRows, inputVector: input},
      dataType: "html",
    });
    
    alert("request opened!");
```

The first alert of the input shows without issue. The second alert showing "request opened!" does not. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this JQuery?  Have you loaded the library?

Comment: Yes! It's been a minute since working on this so I forgot to mention that. I have this at the top: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js">

Comment: Yikes that's very outdated. Just updated it to <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: The code itself should work - even though you did not define any action to happen, in case the `$.ajax()` call is successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet demonstrates that your code basically works - even if the given `url` does not return anything:

```js
// define some constants:
const input=123,ruleNumber=7,numRows=5;

alert(input);
  var request = $.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users", // "ca.py",
  type: "GET",
  data: {id:7,rule: ruleNumber, numSteps: numRows, inputVector: input},
  dataType: "html"
});
alert("request opened!");
// further down:
request.done(function(dat){alert("received:\n"+dat)});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And in case the `url` actually returns something then the `.done()` will also fire.

Comment: That did get it to show the request opened alert, plus the received information. You're right, though, dat is empty. My python code previous printed the result - should it be returning instead? I don't know what update would have triggered that change - Python2->3 or updated Ajax/jQuery?

Comment: Here is the matching piece from the python code:

try:
 form=cgi.FieldStorage()
 #random stuff here
 ca(inputVector, rule, numSteps) #this was previous printing what we wanted to be received on the other end

# For error debugging:
except Exception as fail:
 print("Failure: " + repr(fail))

If I change the ca function to return 0, dat still seems to be empty.

Comment: I have this further down in my javascript and was using msg as the variable that contains what I want back from Python: request.done(function(msg) {
 running=true;

Comment: Maybe you could change your `.done()` function to show you exactly what you received from your `ca.py` script?

Answer (score 0):

Welp, it was one of those "oh my god" type of issues. Thanks to those who posted here - you helped me get much further in my debugging than I did on my own.

The issue is that my hosting platform needs a specifier for Python3. I received the following message back:

> The following python binaries are available:
>
> python3: Python 3.9.7 python3.8: Python 3.8.12 python3.9: Python 3.9.7
>
> Please use the binary for the version of Python you want.

So, I changed my env from python to python3, and we're all set!